# How to create like %keyword% query in MongoDB using Nodejs

Tags: mongodb, angular, mongoose, mean-stack

I am working on a MEAN application and want to implement a search filter. I am passing the search keyword in below route as follows

```
router.route("/places/search/:keyword")
    .get(function (req, res) {

        query = {};
        if (req.params.keyword !== undefined) {
            query = {
                name: { '$regex': new RegExp("^" + req.params.keyword.toLowerCase(), "i") }
            };
        }
        var response = {};
        Place.find(query, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                response = { "error": true, "message": "Error fetching data" };
            } else {
                response = { "error": false, "message": data };
            }
            res.json(response);
        });
    });
```

Above code is doing search like `keyword%` that returns all places having `name` starting with the passed keyword but I want to fetch all places where `name` contains `keyword` either in start, middle or at the end, something like `%keyword%` in MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
router.route("/places/search/:keyword")
    .get(function (req, res) {

        query = {};
        if (req.params.keyword !== undefined) {
            query = {
                name: new RegExp(req.params.keyword, 'i')
            };
        }
        var response = {};
        Place.find(query, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                response = { "error": true, "message": "Error fetching data" };
            } else {
                response = { "error": false, "message": data };
            }
            res.json(response);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

query  like a mongodb and node js

```
getSearch(collection, Name) {
     
        var query =  new RegExp(Name,"i")
        
        return this.connect().then(db => {
            return db.collection(collection).find({ "title": query}).toArray();
          })
```